# pass value through url

Tags: iphone

I have a question.

my URL is some thing like this

http://www.google.com?to=shishir&from=friend

and I have 2 textfields from where I`m getting value of to and from.

I need to set those values of 2 textfields into the URL
to="values from textfield"  from="value from textfield"

to create a somewhat called a dynamic URL.

how can i do it

quick reply is always appreciated

regards
shishir

Answer (score 2):

You can use NSString's `+stringWithFormat` method to create your string:

```
NSString* urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.google.com?to=%@&from=%@", field1.text, field2.text];
```

Comment: this one is showing error saying


too many arguments.....suggestions

regards
shishir

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty could be:

1. get the text into 2 arrays.
2. sprintf to the final string variable.

```
char* from;
char* to;
char* url; // string of the final URL

sprintf(url, "http://www.google.com?from=%s&to=%s", from, to);
```

This should do the trick as needed, obviously you may need to do the magic to get the content of the from and to strings in the pointers and allocate memory to url, but other than that I guess, this takes care of the issue.

Comment: this where also,i want to put values into URL

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com/a?to="valueshere"&from="valueher"];


help.always appreciated 
regards